# Change color ROW on multiple choice dropdown menu with JQUERY

Tags: php, jquery

I all. I would like to achive this:
When I change the status of the drop-down menu "status", I wold like to color the row with a respective colour. I would like to use jquery.
SO basically the row will be white if status is "new", yellow if its "progress", green if is "done"... etc etc.
[image]

So far this is what I have done in teh function:

```
function on_status_update(element){ 
var value = $(element).val();
var rowID = $(element).attr("row");  

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'somepage.php', 
    data: {
        update: value,
        id: rowID,
        func: 'status'

    },
    success: function (response) {
        let row = $("select[row='".concat(response.id, "']")).parent().parent();
        row.addClass('blue');

        console.log(response); 
    }}, "json")}
```

And this on the table:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$job_id = $row['id'];
echo "<form action='' method=post>";
echo "<tr style='background-color:".$color." ; class='info status_".$row['status']."'>

            <input type=hidden name=hidden value=" . $row['id'] . ">
           <td class='id'>" . $row['id'] . "</td> 
           <td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['number'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row['device'] . "  </td>
            <td>" . $row['problem'] . "</td>
       <td>
       <select onchange='on_status_update(this)' row='" . ($row['id']) . "' id='status'   
       class='form- 
       control col-sm-10' name='status'>
            <option value='new' ". ($row['status'] == 'new'? 'selected ': '') .">New</option>
            <option value='progress' ". ($row['status'] == 'progress'? 'selected ': '') 
        .">Progress</option>
        ....
        </select>
```

I think I have to modify something in the "success of the function", but I dont get how to do it.
Or is there any other/better method to achive this?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use switch case statement

```
var selectedOption = $('#status').find(':selected').text();
switch (selectedOption) {
 case 'yellow': $('//Class of which element's color to change').css("Background-color","//Color here");
                break;
//Continue for all
}
```